# Spring Data with Integration Test OneToMany ManyToOne

Tags: jpa, integration-testing, one-to-many, spring-data, many-to-one

I know that this topic is not new, but I few days try to solve task.
I have 3 classes - Client, Account and Invoice.
Client has many Accoutns, Account has many Invoices.
I mapped them:
**Client**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CLIENT")
public final class Client implements Serializable {
...
    @Column(length = 36, nullable = false, unique = true, updatable = false)
    private String uuid;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "client", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Account> accounts;
...
}
```

**Account**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ACCOUNT")
public final class Account implements Serializable {
...
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "client_uuid", referencedColumnName = "uuid", nullable = false)
    private Client client;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "account", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Invoice> invoices;
...
}
```

**Invoice**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "INVOICE")
public final class Invoice implements Serializable {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "account_uuid", referencedColumnName = "uuid", nullable = false)
    private Account account;
}
```

I use Spring Data Jpa:

```
@Repository
public interface SpringDataClientRepository extends ClientRepository, JpaRepository<Client, Integer> {
```

Others the same.

When I try to run ITests, test with client work fine:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { JpaConfig.class, ITDaoConfig.class })
public class ITClientRepository {
private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ITClientRepository.class);

@Autowired
private ClientRepository clientRepository;

@Test
@Transactional
public void testSaveClient() {
log.info("testSaveClient start");

Client client = new Client();
client.setName("testSaveClient");
client.setUuid("client-testSaveClient");
client.setTelephone("12345679");

Account account = new Account();
account.setClient(client);
account.setMoneyCount(10);
account.setUuid("client-testSaveClient");
client.addAccount(account);

log.info(client.toString());
Client getClient = clientRepository.save(client);
log.info(client.toString());
```

It saves client and account in. But this test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { JpaConfig.class, ITDaoConfig.class })
public class ITAccountRepository {
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ITAccountRepository.class);

    @Autowired
    private AccountRepository accountRepository;

    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void testSaveAccount() {
    log.info("testSaveAccount start");

    Client client = new Client();
    client.setName("testSaveAccount");
    client.setTelephone("12345679");
    client.setUuid("account-testSaveAccount");
    client.setId(200);
    // Client saved in db

    Account account = new Account();
    account.setClient(client);
    account.setMoneyCount(15);
    account.setUuid("account-testSaveAccount");
    client.addAccount(account);

    Invoice invoice = new Invoice();
    invoice.setAccount(account);
    invoice.setAmount(11);
    Date date = new Date();
    invoice.setCreated(date);
    invoice.setUuid("account-testSaveClient");
    invoice.setDescription("Description of invoice");
    account.addInvoice(invoice);

    log.info(account.toString());
    Account getAccount = accountRepository.save(account);
    log.info(account.toString());
```

fail with:

```
 Caused by: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: Not-null property references a transient value - transient instance must be saved before current operation : projects.model.Invoice.account -> projects.model.Account
```

**I want** that all Invoices will be saved if I save Account of those invoices. And the same with Client - all Accounts will be saved if I save Client of them. 
**How I do this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a change to have a unidirectional relationship with composition:

**Client**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CLIENT")
public final class Client extends BaseEntity {
    @Column(length = 36)
    private String uuid;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "client_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private List<Account> accounts;
 }
```

**Invoice**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "INVOICE")
public final class Invoice extends BaseEntity {
    @Column(length = 36)
    private String uuid;
}
```

**Account**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ACCOUNT")
public final class Account extends BaseEntity {
    @Column(length = 36)
    private String uuid;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "account_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private List<Invoice> invoices;
 }
```

In the test, I left everything like it was. And it all works now.

Comment: So basically, you only removed the `JoinColumn` annotation from the `Invoice` entity ?